# mailbox implementation in php

Tags: php, imap

i am not able to fetch attachments using imap functions, i am getting errors like this when i am trying to fetch the attachments

**Warnings:**

```
Warning: fopen(./Chrysanthemum.jpg) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in l/mail_thyagi/receivemail.class.php on line 167

Warning: fwrite(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in mail_thyagi/receivemail.class.php on line 168

Warning: fclose(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in mail_thyagi/receivemail.class.php on line 169
```

thanks

Comment: Any code? Are you familiar with the output of `imap_fetchstructure()`?

Comment: The information is not enough. From what you have pasted we understand you cannot open file with fopen... and nothing related to php-imap. Share more of your code so somebody may help you out. Otherwise, you should ask a fortune teller to predict your problem :D

Answer (score 0):

Have you bothered to read the error message at all? What could possibly "permission denied" mean when you try to, well, open a file for writing? Are you still sure that this has something to do with IMAP? ...